# system-for-setting scope and difference from game-rec

Tags: discussion, tags

While reading [What is a good system for a political espionage game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49504/what-is-a-good-system-for-a-political-espionage-game), I saw the [system-for-setting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-for-setting) tag, and I don't see the difference to a tightly formulated (i.e. correctly asked) [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) question.

It is currently used 5 times in total, 4 of which are also tagged [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation)

- The aforementioned [What is a good system for a political espionage game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49504/what-is-a-good-system-for-a-political-espionage-game)
- [I want to run an RPG inspired by Monáe's 'Metropolis' concept series](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29095/i-want-to-run-an-rpg-inspired-by-mon%C3%A1es-metropolis-concept-series)
- [Alternate class system for MtG inspired setting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29282/alternate-class-system-for-mtg-inspired-setting)
- [System for Setting: Misfits](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9907/system-for-setting-misfits)
- [System for Setting: Joe Abercrombie's The First Law](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8349/system-for-setting-joe-abercrombies-the-first-law)

The last two questions were both asked by gomad, and he added the tag to both questions in Sept. 2011, which means the tag might have missed some game-rec-reforms and -metas.

[game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) questions need to be specific, with the asker clearly stating which part of the game is important to him and asking for a system that has mechanics that supports this kind of thing. This is not much different from specifying a setting, though potentially less precise ("Interstellar space warfare, where the players are working for the underdog faction" vs. "Star Wars Rebels").

In fact, many game-rec-questions are about recreating the feel of a specific movie/TV series/book/...

That being said, I doubt that the tag has any merit and vote for burnination or synonymization.

Comment: I have updated the tag wiki for [system-for-setting] to hopefully highlight exactly what the tag means and what expectations using sets for Qs and As.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why we need to eliminate the tag.  Some people have clearly used it and found it useful.  Does it meet any of the objective bad-tag criteria? If not, just let it go. The point of the emergent tagging system is that it doesn't need over-curation. Sometimes, tags are subsets of another tag, and that's OK.

Comment: What about it appearing to be a straightforward synonym for [[tag:game-recommendation]]? I may be misunderstanding the meta question, but I thought that was the basic issue.

Comment: It is not a synonym, it is more specific.

Comment: Okay. That's easy to miss in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem to be hurting anything (the tag isn't replacing a more useful tag, for example), and I think it's a useful tag for attracting experts *and* for sorting questions. [game-rec] has an extremely broad mandate: a quick glance over recently active questions finds questions about systems for a particular group makeup (size, experience, age), the difference between two systems, and systems which support particular moral themes, as well as many questions which could use the [system-for-setting] tag.

As someone looking for a specific question, [system-for-setting] narrows this down so I don't have to slog through "Game for my 11-year-old who likes Lord of the Rings and Harry Potter" questions when looking for the best system to run a game about Rangers of the North.

As an answerer, it helps me sort out the kind of experience I should have in order to answer a question.

And as a site user, favouriting or blacklisting the tag helps me focus on the kind of [game-rec] questions I'm interested in: the ones I may be able to answer or improve, the ones I'm most confident voting on. (If I only work in homebrew worlds, hiding the [sys-for-set] tag could be *really* helpful in bringing my attention where it's useful).

**I think we could tag this more aggressively.**

...but it's not a tag that querents are likely to stumble across while writing their question, which brings all of this into doubt for me as it hints this isn't a *natural* tag. Or maybe it just needs re-phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

With only a few instances, this is one that we should just remove and let it age away.

No need for outside intervention. A few edits and we're done.

Comment: Yeah, burnination is unnecessarily drastic. Synonyming might be useful... but probably not if it's only been used three other times since creation. Just editing it off the questions is plenty.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Editing off the questions _is_ burnination! (Are you mistaking it with blacklisting?)

Comment: @dopoelgreener I always though "burninating" meant burning them to the ground and sowing the land with salt… so yeah, maybe I am. :)

Comment: Generally we use "burninate" for SE coming in and removing a tag. Blacklist prevents it from rising again. What we cna do should probably be best termed as "editing to remove, and let age away" way less awesome.